# How to install Adobe Flash to Chromium browser

Tags: apt, software-installation, flash

I have downloaded flashplayer from a site and tried to install it from the terminal but I get an error.

[image]

I tried this command which I have found in another posting and when tried to install the package got same error.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Comment: Install it by `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: well , it says that the newest version is already installed but im opening a site needs flashplayer plugin and says Flash detection failed

Comment: What browser do you use? And which Ubuntu version?

Comment: chromium , ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: If you use Chromium, you need pepperflash. It can be installed by `sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin`. Restart the browser after you do it.

Comment: sorry for annoying but im still noob in that
i got
`Package adobe-flashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'adobe-flashplugin' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you run root operations, such as `apt-get`, you absolutely *must* use `sudo`. Otherwise, you will get the "Permission Denied" error. The message even hints at what you should be trying: "Are you root?"

Use `sudo apt-get install flashplayer` to install that package.

As Pilot6 has pointed out in the comments, you need `pepperflash` for Chromium. However, the package name he gave you was not correct. You want:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

That will install Flash Player for Chromium (and I believe Firefox). It will start working either after you restart Chromium or reboot the computer.

If it doesn't, run

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

to manually install it to Chromium.

Comment: There is no package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's installing right now on my 16.04 machine.

Comment: You are correct. It is in multiverse now.

Comment: well , now after i did what @Pilot6 gave me it updated somthing but got same error then i used this command  it started downloading and finally setting up the plugin thank u both guys